# How to install packages into specific virtualenv created by conda

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

I want to install python packages after virtualenv is created by conda.
But I got the following error, does anyone know how to install packages into virtualenv created by conda ?

```
/Users/jzhang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
(env_2) jzhangMBPr:env_2 jzhang$ conda install numpy
Fetching package metadata .........


CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError: Could not find environment: /Users/jzhang/anaconda/envs/env_2 .
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

Comment: You used venc or ```conda create``` to build this env? What is the output of the recommended command-line?

Answer (score 7):

First, enter into an environment that you have created by the following command:

```
activate your_environment_name
```

Then, you will be in particular in your environment. Now, you can install numpy using this command:

```
conda install -c anaconda numpy
```

Answer (score 5):

From the help:

> Target Environment Specification:
> -n ENVIRONMENT, --name ENVIRONMENT
> Name of environment.

So all you need is to do:
`conda install -n YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_NAME PACKAGE`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't use conda but as far as I understand from the [docs](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/test-drive.html#managing-environments), it should work like this:

1. Create your env `conda create --name snowflakes biopython`
2. Activate your env `source activate snowflakes`
3. Install what you need `conda install what-you-want` or `pip install what-you-want`

Comment: Don't use ```pip install X```, use ```conda install X```. The latter will install the given binaries while pip will do the usual stuff, most of  the times compiling from the sources (which defeats somehow the purpose of conda). Only use this, if there is no conda-package.

Comment: @sascha conda install doesn't always cover pip install.
For instance, `conda install graphviz` installs the graphviz binaries, but not the graphviz Python package. So if you need the Python package you need to run `conda install graphviz && pip install graphviz`.