# No module named 'numpy' after pip/conda install numpy

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv, conda

I have conda and python 3.5 on Windows 7. I am working in virtual environment (`activate tensorflow`). I successfully executed

```
pip install numpy 
conda install numpy
```

When I ran

```
import numpy as np
```

I get back:

```
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

What is wrong?

Update:

Here are some troubleshooting steps (all ran in virtual environment):

```
where conda
```

returns:

```
C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\conda
C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\conda.b
at
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe



where python
```

returns:

```
C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\python.exe



where pip
```

returns:

```
C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\pip.exe
```

Comment: Do you have more than one virtualenvs in conda?

Comment: Do not install packages with both pip and conda. What do `which conda`, `which python` and `which pip` say?

Comment: @ElBaulP no, only `root` and `tensorflow`. I am working in `tensorflow`

Comment: @MaxNoe where do I run these commands? In cmd `which` is not recognized.

Comment: I guess then this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41802528/1612432

Comment: Oh, you are on windows?

Comment: @MaxNoe correct

Comment: Then it's `where conda`, `where python` and `where pip`

Comment: @MaxNoe I added output of `where` commands

Answer (score 2):

You said you have two virtual environments, as I pointed out in my comment, this could help:

1. Activate your env `conda activate tensorflow`
2. Install numpy  `conda install numpy`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41802528/1612432

Comment: I don't think `root` is environment. `root` is  base case. It is always active. On windows 7 I normally run `activate tensorflow`, and I aready did `conda install numpy`

Comment: Use `conda activate tensorflow` instead of `source activate tensorflow`. I have just tried to create an empty environment and executed the steps above and worked.

Comment: `conda activate tensorflow` returns `CommanNotFoundError: 'activate'`

Comment: Something was wrong with my old virtual environment. I created new one and everything worked.